# How should I build this Laravel controller and use it with both vue components and blade? Should I make an api controller or web controller or both?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

So right now I have blade templates that contain vue components.

One component is "ProductsGrid.vue", which makes an axios request to an api endpoint to get the products from the database, then lists them in a card view.

The endpoint in api.php

```
Route::get('/products', ListProductsController::class)->name('getProducts'); // returns collection of products with pagination, so basically JSON.
```

The web.php that sends you the view

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('products');
})->name('home');
```

and then the blade template

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <products-grid></products-grid>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

(the layouts.app just contains the div#app div, this way  works as intended.)

I'm about to code the basic CRUD for the products model, but I'm kind of overwhelmed. I'm new at these things and I don't know what would be the good or bad thing to do.

I think I have these 2 options:

1. make an api endpoint for the update method, create a vue component for editing and submit the form via axios.
2. make web.php endpoints for the edit and update methods, and just put a blade template on the edit endpoint and pass the data to the view, and submit the request as you would by default.

But is it okay if I do it like this (2)?

My main problem is, which is itching my brain: the index returns a collection from api.php, the show method returns a view from web.php, the edit method returns a view from web.php, the update method returns a json from api.php, etc.. so it varies. A lot. And it looks bad to me.

Or should I make 2 controllers, one for the API and one for the web? OR how does this work?

I'm sorry if I'm writing gibberish, this day has been a long one and this is my first time using vue components ever.

If you need additional info, comment and I'll update it as soon as possible.

Comment: If you're going to use Vue for the page itself, don't use Blade. Stick with pure Vue components/routes for the pages and use Laravel for the API. The only Blade file that Laravel really needs to return is the master layout.

Comment: So I should treat Vue as a standalone application?

Comment: Is there a reason to use it like I tried to? Like blade templates and components inside those? Or is it just like a "beginner's thoughts" kind of thing? :D

Comment: Probably just beginner's thoughts. A lot of the Laravel tutorials and documentation reference Blade because it's Laravel's main templating engine. When you introduce Vue, Vue becomes the driver of the front-end. Trying to mix both Blade and Vue templates can lead to headaches. Laravel has [Inertia](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/frontend#using-vue-react) to bridge the two if you want to use it, but I've never used it so I can't say much about it.

Comment: Interesting. However, I feel like I might've misunderstood my task then, because it says that the card view and the cart must be vue components, so my brain tied it to "okay, so those are vue components, the rest is not". I might give a try to inertiajs, I don't know yet.  All these things are so new to me and I'm a bit afraid of messing it up.

Comment: You may want to ask for clarification of what the task is looking for, then. If it's for a job, they may have a standard in place that you'll want to stick with. If it's a class, the teacher may be able to explain what they're looking for.

Comment: yes it's a teacher. I think I'll do that tomorrow then. Thank you for your help and for your time!

Comment: I'll leave the question open in case someone has ideas too